# Use a Computed Property as DisplayColumn in ASP.Net Dynamic Data?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I am trying to display a 'Software Release' table in an asp.net dynamic data site.  The Release table has a build number stored as three int fields (Major, Minor, Build). I'm using EntityFramework, so I have an EF model bound to my database schema.  In my dynamic data site, I want the build number to show up as a single field (Major.Minor.Build) wherever the Release object is shown (particularly when it shows as a foreign key on pages for related objects).  Since this 'computed column' is not a field in my database, there doesn't seem to be anyway to get the Dynamic-Data to recognize or display it.  I can add a property to the Release object (since it is a partial class generated by EF), but Dynamic-Data won't recognize it, because it isn't a 'column'.  I want to edit the Release as three separate fields (major, minor, build), but when it is displayed, I want it to show as a single field.  The DynamicData framework doesn't seem to support composite fields, and it won't display/bind to properties on the object if they aren't in the EF model. How do I make the formatted version number property the default display value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are binding to a DataTable/DataSet returned from the database, or if you are binding to a Release object itself. Nor which kind of control.

If you are binding to a DataSet/DataTable, simply change your SQL to return the version as one field:

```
SELECT table1.Major + '.' + table1.Minor + '.' + table1.Build AS Version ....
```

However, if you are binding to an object to, say, a DropDownList, I **think** that if you override the ToString method, it will become the Display value in the DropDownList:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return _major.ToString & '.' & _minor.ToString & '.' & _build.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Correction, overriding the ToString and NOT providing a DisplayColumn attribute in the meta-data does work.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an metadata class as you would when doing any dynamic data ui customization.
Then you create a UIHint in the metadata to tell the dynamic data what control to use for your custom object.
E.G.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EMetadata))]
public partial class E{


    public string RefNR {
        get {
            return "E" + this.EntryID.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
        }
    }

}

public partial class EMetadata {
    [UIHint("Text")]
    public object RefNR;
}
```